# Node JS Worker Threads core usage

Tags: node.js, multithreading

I have heard about a new features in Node.JS, the Worker Threads for multi-threading (https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_worker_threads).
So now, I can fork a new threads in a single Node.JS process, sounds great. Especially for not blocking the event loop.

But, I do not understand one thing, the Worker Threads can access only on a single core on the process?

So Node.JS can use only a single core with multi-threading?

Comment: 1 worker thread uses 1 core. Multiple worker threads use multiple cores. The same applies to any Node processes.

Comment: so i can use Multiple worker threads in Node JS? You have any guide or article about this? thanks

Comment: See child_process docs for starters. It's the same thing, just more convenient and with less overhead.